# Выделяется ли "где-то" запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

Повздорили с преподавателем русского языка насчет запятой перед словом "где-то". Само предложение:

"Только в выжженном, обесцвеченном солнцем июльском небе где-то по-прежнему звенели жаворонки" (Ан. Иванов).

Преподаватель сказала, что нужна запятая, так как в данном предложении "где-то" идет после одного обстоятельства места (июльское небо), и само "где-то" является здесь обстоятельством места и тем самым они становятся однородными.
Заранее большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вы правы, никакого обособления тут не надо.

Answer (score 2):

*Только в выжженном, обесцвеченном солнцем **июльском небе где-то** по-прежнему звенели жаворонки.*

Запятая не ставится, так как отношения между обстоятельствами **неоднородные.** Хотя они оба являются обстоятельствами **места**, но семантика у них разная. Небо — это общее пространство, а где-то — это часть этого пространства.

Примеры:

*Пахло смолой, озером и земляникой; **где-то в небе** верещали невидимые пичужки.* Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Трудно быть богом (1963).

*Он жил **где-то в нашем доме**, и я несколько раз встречал его на лестнице..*.[Виктор Пелевин. Ника (1992)]

В Нацкорпусе много таких примеров.

Comment: Кстати, я тут задался вопросом, а однородными ли или неоднородными обстоятельствами будет считаться ряд местоименных наречий в предложении вроде: *Два дня мы ехали без цели, ехали где-то(,) куда-то(,) зачем-то... *

Comment: Да, обстоятельства однородные, и это подсказывает нам перечислительная интонация.  Семантика разная, но в данном случае сближенная общей темой неопределенности, отсутствием цели. Обычно о сближенном значении мы говорим для определений:  Стояла темная, безлунная ночь (тёмная, так как безлунная).

Comment: Понял, спасибо)